# Java code to generate private key and self signed certificate

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, keystore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate certificates, public and private keys with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925377/generate-certificates-public-and-private-keys-with-java)

I want to generate private key and self signed certificate using Java code and export it into files. When I searched through net I am getting details only achieving through openssl or keytool commands, but not through java code. I would like not to use any third party library.

Below are the commands which creates key and self signed certificate, which I want to do the same using java code.

```
       openssl req -new -text -out server.req

       openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -out server.key

       openssl req -x509 -in server.req -text -key server.key -out server.crt
```

Any kind of help or suggestion will be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634124/how-to-generate-sign-and-import-ssl-certificate-from-java?lq=1
and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925377/generate-certificates-public-and-private-keys-with-java?rq=1
?

Comment: I highly recommend using BouncyCastle (http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).

Comment: Have a look at this [page](http://www.mayrhofer.eu.org/create-x509-certs-in-java).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634124/how-to-generate-sign-and-import-ssl-certificate-from-java?lq=1