# Set Subject Alternative Names programmatically in Java

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate

I am using something similar to [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25567377/1156544). How can I add set the **Subject Alternative Names** in my certificate programmatically using `sun.security`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, it was a bit tricky to trace several sources but here it is the clue (in case it can help anyone in future as I have been helped other times):

```
CertificateExtensions ext = new CertificateExtensions();

ext.set(SubjectAlternativeNameExtension.NAME, new SubjectAlternativeNameExtension(....*));

// * a `GeneralNames` object including a `GeneralName` object including (for example) an `IPAddressName` object.
```

And then pass the object `ext` to the constructor of the certificate.

Comment: That's correct. You figured before I could comment. Subjectalternativename is defined as extension. So you should create a new object of type CertificateExtension.